# How can I search for and remove an escaped character from an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, escaping

I am reading a line of code in from a source file on disk and the line is a string, and it is of a string that contains HTML code in it:

```
line = @"format = @"<td width=\"%@\">";"
```

I need to remove the escaped characters from the html string. So any place that there is a '\"', I need to replace it with ''. I tried this:

```
[line stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\""" withString:@""];
```

But it only removed the '\' character, not the accompanying '"'. How can I remove the escaped '"' from this string?

EDIT: The key part of this problem is that I need to figure out a way to identify the location of the first @", and the closing " of the string declaration, and ignore/remove everything else. If there is a better way to accomplish this I am all ears.

Comment: The slash isn't a part of the string; it's only present in the literal code so that the compiler knows that the `"` following it doesn't end the string. You can't remove the \ because it's not really there.

Comment: The purpose of my app is to evaluate code files. The \ is there when I read the string in from the file. So I literally have a string that looks like above: @"format = @"<td width=\"%@\">";"

Comment: Oh, all right. So you want to replace "slash followed by double quote" with "double quote"? Or remove those two altogether? The nature of this problem makes your question a little hard to read, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, I want to replace the "slash followed by a double quote" with nothing. I want to remove it. I'll try and edit the question again.

Comment: It's not really your fault; it's just naturally hard to mark this kind of construct up, and hard to distinguish whether you typed a double quote or two single quotes enclosing nothing.

Comment: Waitaminnit -- your edit sounds like a completely different problem. If you're trying to parse that literal `NSString`, `@"<td width=\"%@\">"` out, you might want to look at `NSScanner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@""]
```

The replacement string there is a slash, which has to be escaped in the literal replacement string using another slash, followed by a quote, which also has to be escaped in the literal by a slash.

Answer (score -1):

Try use this:

```
NSString *unfilteredString = @"!@#$%^&*()_+|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[unfilteredString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Result: %@", resultString);
```